# how to pause openldap with syncrepl replication?

Tags: linux, centos, ldap, centos7, openldap

I followed this [link](https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=openldap&f=6) and setup two multi-master open-ldap server.

Everything work fine.

I want to test changes on one master.

**How can I pause replication ?**

OS: CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core)

openldap: openldap-servers-2.4.44-15.el7_5.x86_64

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Temporarily disconnect the replicas from each other to see whether replication catches up after reconnect?

Comment: @MichaelStröder no I just want to stop replication and test a schema change before applying on both servers, one will be "offline" while the other will still service ldap requests.

Comment: I would not test new schema with MMR replicas. You should use a separate test installation for that.